# How do you persistently format a TextBox to display a numeric value?

Tags: vba, excel, ms-office

I'm sure this is a simple question, with a simple answer, but I can't find it.

I've inherited a spreadsheet that I have to fix.  Whoever wrote it made extensive use of VBA and VBA UserForms for inputting data.  On one form, textual and numeric information is entered and then saved to a record on a specific worksheet.  This spreadsheet is used to log project information.  It gets copied, and re-copied again and again.  With each re-copy, it is cleared and used for the next project.

A user has sent me a spreadsheet of one of these major projects.  The VBA, data-entry UserForm has a problem.  One `TextBox`, which accepts either text or numbers, is always reformatting the numbers as dates when you exit the field!?  I've tripled-checked the VBA code.  There is no special `OnEnter` or `OnExit` code related to this field that reformats the data.  Furthermore, I can't find a `Format` property that is associated with the `TextBox` from within the designer.

I'm a C/C# developer, not a VBA developer.  Still, this "simple" IDE has me stumped.  I can't find the property that re-formats the `TextBox` display value.

How can I fix the `TextBox` so that it persistently interprets numbers as numbers and not as dates?

**FURTHER NOTE**

It is worth mentioning two things.  First, user's can't modify these forms or VBA code.  The underlying modules are password protected and only myself and a couple managers know the password.  Furthermore, no one touches the code because I'm the only developer within the company and everyone is a bit scare that they might break something.

Second, something in the file may have been corrupt.  When this file was sent to me, the user also mentioned that the worksheet that he was working on was renamed.  It appears that something didn't save properly because the WorkSheet tab was renamed a random hex string value.

Everything appears to be functioning as normal on this form, other than these two issues.  Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is this textbox on a userform or embedded in the worksheet?

Comment: @enderland This is on a UserForm, not a worksheet.  However, once you exist the TextBox on the field, the data converts to a date.  When you save the data, it posts it as a date to the WorkSheet record.

Comment: @RLH can you clarify for me: when you type something into a textbox and hit TAB or navigate away the data in the textbox is implicitly converted to a date? Can you identify the name of the textbox and show us the code? If the textbox name was textbox1 then look for `Private Sub TextBox1_Change()`. Also can you show the code for the `Save` button?

Comment: mehow, that is correct.  Also, if you go back into the textbox, delete the information, re-enter it, and tab out again, it goes back to being a date.

Comment: @RLH let's go in a [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40510/userform-and-textbox-solving)

Comment: @RLH also, there is no property responsible for the text format on a textbox. There must be a sub or event triggered if the data is being converted to date. Dont waste more time looking at the properties, try to find the code triggered to format the data

Answer (score 1):

You can force the proper format by using **cLng**:

First enter =TODAY() in cell A1 and then run:

```
Sub TextBoxIssue()
    With ActiveSheet.Shapes("TextBox 1").TextFrame.Characters
        .Text = Range("A1").Value
    End With

    MsgBox "However when we use cLng......"

    With ActiveSheet.Shapes("TextBox 1").TextFrame.Characters
        .Text = CLng(Range("A1").Value)
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks GS, but this isn't quite what I need.  I want to fix the field on the UserForm, not the outputted information to the WorkSheet.  Do you have any clue how to fix the UserForm?

Comment: It should not matter if the TextBox resides on the worksheet or in a UserForm.  It should not matter if the information source is a worksheet cell or a VBA variable, or another userform object.  At some point the data gets placed in the TextBox......it is at this point the **cLng()** should be used.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to adapt this into the VBA.  However, I think the greater question that I'd like to have answered is How is the auto-formatting taking place to begin with?  There is on VBA code that forces this to happen.  However, all questions related to VBA field formatting have all involved VBA code.  What might I be missing?

Comment: The "greater question" is very valid.....it appears that when the macro picks up **Range.Value**, it interprets it using **.NumberFormat** implicitly.

Comment: It's not picking up a range, though.  You open the form, enter the data and, when you're finished, hit save.  This problematic field is in the middle of the data-entry process.  When you exit the field, your data isn't being posted.  Data is being posted to a Cell in a WorkSheet only when you hit the Save button.  Since the field reformats your data when you exit the field on the form, the data does get posted as a date.   I could post-format the worksheet, but the problem is that the user gets confused when he sees his number entry transition to a date when he exits the TextBox.

Answer (score 1):

There is most certainly code that is formatting that text on exiting the textbox. You just haven't found it yet. If you go into the Userforms class module and select the textbox from the left dropdown, you can see all of the events in the right dropdown. The bolded events are in use. I assume you've already checked all those, but that's the place to start.

Next, look for custom class modules that use the WithEvents keyword. They can trigger events outside of the userform's class module.

Finally, search the code for all instances of `=Format(tbxName.Text,"mm/dd/yyy")` or some such code. Somewhere the code is probably using the Format function to fill that textbox.